# Which pattern is used to make the app look like

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

I am newbie in iOS development and making a app in swift. But I am confused what to use in the design to make look like it. Should I use table view or collection view.

I have attached the screenshot for same.

[image: Pic for reference]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A collection view would be more appropriate. In addition, iOS 14 collection view enhancements suggest that Apple is very slowly phasing out table views completely, because it provides new kinds of collection view cells that emulate most kinds of table view cells.

Comment: Can we add image, label and textfield in collection view as given above.?

Comment: Each cell is a view. You can add whatever subviews you want to the view.